# When the tensile force is equal to the weight of the body

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

I have met a lot of problems where the tensile force is different from $mg$, while in this one problem in the solutions it is written only that the tensile force is equal to mg. So if someone has time to explain to me when the tensile force is equal to $mg$, I would be grateful.

[image: The picture in question:]

edit: I forgot to add that the mass m2 is moving upwards by the tensile force caused by m3.

Comment: If you mean that the tensile force $F_{x1}$ is equal to $m_1g$, then it is due to newton's second law. As the block $m_1$ is at rest (I suppose), then the forces acting on the block must be oposite each other, which means that $F_{x1} = m_1g$. If this weren't the case, then block 1 would move.

Answer (score 0):

In simple word the tensile force is equal to weight of body only if the string has negligible weight, means it’s light and moreover it should be continuous if these two conditions met then tensile force is equal to mg

Answer (score 0):

For any body whatsoever in 2 Dimensions, all three of the following equations must hold true:

$$\Sigma F_x = ma_x$$
$$\Sigma F_y = ma_y$$
$$\Sigma M_z = I \alpha_z$$

Or in other words, "Sum of the x-direction forces on the body equals the mass times acceleration in the x direction"...."Sum of the y-direction forces on the body equals the mass times acceleration in the y direction"...."Sum of the z-direction moments on the body (around a particular point chosen) equals the moment of intertia times angular acceleration in the z direction."

For your example, you can ignore the moments equation.* Your task now is to draw a free body diagram for each of the 3 blocks in isolation, and write out the $F_x$ and $F_y$ equations.  This will be the set of equations you use to find all your unknowns.

This should be your general approach to any rigid body mechanics problem.  Rules like "Tension = mg" are not always true. The above equations are.

*Footnote: Block 2 does have a moment because the frictional force is not acting through the center of mass of the block, but the implicit assumption in the problem is that this is not enough to flip it over or cause any noticeable effect.